# Add an array to an existing object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

"I have an array:

`myArray = []`

I'm looping through some data and adding it to my array:

`myArray.push(listItem)`

I would then like to add an array of objects to this array. The end result is that inside each of these objects is an array of image paths

```
0:
id: "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa0Q"
images: [{…}]
title: "My Title 1"
1:
id: "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa023"
images: [{…}]
title: "My Title 2"
```

I've tried the following:

```
var newIndex = index - 1;
var imagesArray = [];
imagesArray.push(imageString);
this.myArray[newIndex]["images"] = imagesArray;
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @mplungjan it works in both cases, `.key` works but with `["key"]` it doesnot, just checked

Comment: what do you want from this array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `find` a desired object in `yourArray` and assign a desired value:

```js
let yourArray = [];

yourArray.push({id: "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa0Q", title: "My Title 1"});
yourArray.push({id: "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa023", title: "My Title 2"});

yourArray.find(f=>f.id = "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa0Q").images = [];

console.log(yourArray);
```

Or safer version with checking whether desired object is existing:

```js
let yourArray = [];

yourArray.push({id: "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa0Q", title: "My Title 1"});
yourArray.push({id: "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa023", title: "My Title 2"});

let desiredObject = yourArray.find(f=>f.id = "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa0Q");
if (desiredObject)
    desiredObject.images = [];

console.log(yourArray);
```

**UPDATE:**

If you dont' have access to the ID in the addImage function, then this is the way  via index:

```
yourArray[0].images = [];
```

In addition, you can find index via `findIndex` method:

```js
let yourArray = [];

yourArray.push({id: "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa0Q", title: "My Title 1"});
yourArray.push({id: "8okCSIfrSTugwBW4Oa023", title: "My Title 2"});


let index = yourArray.findIndex(f => f.title == 'My Title 1');
if (index != -1)
    yourArray[index].images = [];

console.log(yourArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! - Unfortunately, I don't have access to the ID in the addImage function, which is why I was trying to do it via index...if that makes any sense.

Comment: `myArray[0].images = [];`

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. The issue is that I don't have access to that data to search for the index. Unfortunately I cannot match up the titles, IDs or anything like that. I may have 200 items, some with 1 image, some with 20. I don't know.

Comment: When I push an item into the array, it looks like it's returned as a string: 

0: "21,0,1,"Issue 1",,"","I have some comments that are ↵↵going here on multiple lines",,"2019/11/28, 12:20:55","",""↵"
1: "23,1,2,"Issue 2",,"","",,"2019/12/02, 11:37:38","",""↵" - So when I try something like `yourArray[0].images = [];`, it states ` Cannot create property 'images' on string`

Comment: @que so you can create `images` like that: `yourArray[0].images = [];` where `0` is array index.

Comment: @Que Please update the question instead of pasting code into comments

Comment: Thanks very much @StepUp. Thanks for the contribution mplungjan